# How to extract text from TextView type of H5 file?

Tags: python, textview, hdf5, h5py

I have an H5 file with following structure:

[image]

How do I import the text that is in "description" which is of type TextView into a variable using python?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read h5py documentation? Have you tried to code anything?

Not sure what type `TextView` is. How did you determine the type?

`cc`, `bb` and `aa` are HDF5 Groups.
`description` is a HDF5 Dataset.

You can access the `description` dataset with the following:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('SRCatalogue.h5') as h5f:
    # This returns an h5py dataset object as descr
    descr = h5f['/cc/bb/aa/descripton']
    # Add this to get info about the data:  
    print(descr.shape, descr.dype)
```